# Нужны ли запятые в этих предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, прямая-речь, как

*А у нас довольно много регионов-банкротов, таких, как Курганская область.*
Нужна ли запятая перед "как"?

*Когда медики ставят резонный вопрос: «Почему наши зарплаты в два-три раза меньше, чем те, которыми отчитываются чиновники?» – им отвечают, что майские указы и дорожные карты устанавливают целевые показатели именно средних зарплат медработников по региону. Но они не имеют прямого отношения к зарплате отдельного работника.*
Какие знаки поставить перед словом "им": только тире, или запятую и тире, или просто запятую? (Это цитата, точность которой важно сохранить).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А. А у нас довольно **много** регионов-банкротов, **таких как** Курганская область.

Таких как — **составной союз**.

Сравнить:

А у нас довольно **много** регионов-банкротов,  **например** Курганская область.

А у нас довольно много **таких** регионов-банкротов,  **как** Курганская область.

Союз ***таких как*** расчленяется на местоименную и союзную часть: ***таких...как***

Б. Когда медики ставят резонный вопрос: **«Почему наши зарплаты в два-три раза меньше, чем те, которыми отчитываются чиновники?»** – им отвечают...

Тире (а не запятая)  ставится, так как **прямая речь вопросительная.**

Пояснение

**При выборе знака надо учитывать следующее:** 1) есть ли запятая в словах автора; 2) есть ли  знак в прямой речи (вопросительный, восклицательный, многоточие).

**Запятая** ставится (сохраняется), если она была в словах автора и прямая речь **повествовательная** (тогда прямая речь интонационно вписывается в предложение): **Ко мне подходит Борис, говорит: «Хорошо сбил, замечательно», но глаза его блестят, полные зависти.**

Если эти условия не соблюдаются, то ставится **тире**.

1) Она сказала: **«Нынче, говорят, в университете уже мало занимаются науками» — и подозвала свою собачку Сюзетку** (Л. Т.) — тире перед союзом И при однородных сказуемых (она сказала и подозвала). **Нет запятой** на месте вставки прямой речи.

2) **На вопрос мой: «Жив ли старый смотритель?» — никто не мог дать мне удовлетворительного ответа** (П.);
 — тире после вопросительного знака, которым заканчивается прямая речь. Кроме того, запятой не было на месте вставки.

3) **И только когда он шептал: «Мама! Мама!» — ему становилось как будто легче** (Ч.) — запятая на месте вставки есть, но прямая речь восклицательная, поэтому ставится тире.

Розеналь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159

Answer (score 2):

**А у нас довольно много регионов-банкротов, таких как Курганская область.**

> Однако в некоторых случаях запятая ставится не перед словом «как», а перед словом «такой»:
>
> 1) если слова «такой как» соотносятся с предшествующим прилагательным: Погода дождливая, такая как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была мрачная, такая как в старинных замках (ср.: Погода такая, как осенью. Обстановка в этом доме была такая, как в старинных замках);
>   ([Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_722))

**Схема: А: «П...?» — а.**

> 6. Если прямая речь находится внутри слов автора, то перед прямой речью ставится двоеточие, после нее - запятая или тире. Как правило, тире ставится в том случае, если после прямой речи по условиям контекста должен стоять вопросительный, восклицательный знаки или многоточие. Слова автора после разрыва пишутся со строчной буквы.

(http://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/11-klass/predlozheniia-s-chuzhoi-rechiu-10913/znaki-prepinaniia-pri-priamoi-rechi-11046/re-49240124-a872-4636-a9bd-f0054a14c7e1)